# Javascript adding functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

To add a function to an object, i write it inside of it like this `AddX`:

```
function Foo()
{
    this.x = 1;

    this.AddX = function(y)
    {
      this.x += y;
    }

}
```

But I found out that other way could be to use `prototype`:

```
function Foo()
{
    this.x = 1;
}

Foo.prototype.AddX = function(y)
{
    this.x += y;
}
```

Using:

```
obj = new Foo;
obj.AddX(5);
alert(obj.x);
```

Result is same in both cases. Which route is best or is there any difference between the two ? Is there any performance issue also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first approach, `addX` is an instance method. Thus each instance of `Foo` will have their own copy of `addX`.

While in the second approach, `addX` is a added onto `prototype`, and each instance of `Foo` shares the same prorotype.

Thus the second approach will save more memory. If you have a large number of instances to be created, then you'd better use the second approach.

Comment: Anyway the second approach is the right one, not only with large numbers of instances.

Answer (score 1):

A prototype is used to add features which are reflected across all instances of the function.

For example:

```
//First, create the custom object "circle"
function circle(){
}
circle.prototype.pi=3.14159
```

[Taken from here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto2.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

in your example there is no difference  between both of them 
but you can use prototype property to add functions to JavaScript built in objects like Date ,String etc...